# CountVectorizer not working for test string in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I've been working on Sentiment Analysis using sklearn. I have a csv file of 3000 odd reviews and I am training my classifier on 60% of those reviews. 
When I try to give a custom review for the classifier to predict the label using CountVectorizer.transform() it is throwing the following error :

```
    Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 864, in transform
    raise ValueError("Vocabulary wasn't fitted or is empty!")
    ValueError: Vocabulary wasn't fitted or is empty!
```

Please Help me, this is the code for fitting the training set :

```
    def preprocess():
        data,target = load_file()
        count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(binary='true',min_df=1)
        data = count_vectorizer.fit_transform(data)
        tfidf_data = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=False).fit_transform(data)
        return tfidf_data
```

And this is the code for predicting the sentiment of a custom review:

```
    def customQuestionScorer(question, clf):
        X_new_tfidf = vectorizer.transform([question]).toarray()
        print (clf.predict(X_new_tfidf))
    q = "I really like this movie"
    customQuestionScorer(q,classifier)
```

Comment: `mn = MultinomialNB()`
`cv = CounterVectorizer()`
`# data is your example, or test, data #`
`X = cv.fit_transform([' '.join(row) for row in data])`
`#y just distributes your data into catagories #`
`y = ["some random thing","some random other thing"]`
`mn.fit(X,y).predict_proba(cv.transform([' '.join([test])]))`

Something like this should work for you.

Comment: You'll also need to solve for cases where data doesn't exist, this model has issues with `NULL` sets.

Answer (score 1):

1. I didn't see classifier here, you are using only transformers (CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer). To get predictions - you must train classifier on output of TfidfTransformer.
2. It's not clear whether you are using same CountVectorizer and TfidfTransformer (which were trained on training set before) to transform test-set texts, or some new. To provide correct input for previously fitted classifier - you have to feed it from previously fitted transformers (Not new).

Look here for good example of text processing http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/grid_search_text_feature_extraction.html#example-model-selection-grid-search-text-feature-extraction-py